# Why Ansible-Tower is ignoring extra variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Trying to lunch a job workflow via REST API and passing extra variables for the playbook to consume, but returned body shows that provided variables are put in `ignored_fields` section.

Used POSTMAN and CURL to run the templates both returned the same result

CURL command

```sh
curl -X POST http://172.16.0.97/api/v2/job_templates/8/launch/ -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer Je
gxwfQrdKQXoRUtNWtWFz62FX5bTy" -d "{\"extra_vars\": {\"vendor\":\"juniper\"}}"
```

Returned body

```
{"job":34,"ignored_fields":{"extra_vars":{"vendor":"juniper"}},"id":34,"type":"job","url":"/api/v2/jobs/34/","related":{"created_by":"/api/v2/users/1/","modified_by":"/api/v2/users/1/","labels":"/api/v2/jobs/34/labels/","inventory":"/api/v2/inventories/1/","project":"/api/v2/projects/7/","extra_credentials":"/api/v2/jobs/34/extra_credentials/","credentials":"/api/v2/jobs/34/credentials/","unified_job_template":"/api/v2/job_templates/8/","stdout":"/api/v2/jobs/34/stdout/","job_events":"/api/v2/jobs/34/job_events/","job_host_summaries":"/api/v2/jobs/34/job_host_summaries/","activity_stream":"/api/v2/jobs/34/activity_stream/","notifications":"/api/v2/jobs/34/notifications/","job_template":"/api/v2/job_templates/8/","cancel":"/api/v2/jobs/34/cancel/","create_schedule":"/api/v2/jobs/34/create_schedule/","relaunch":"/api/v2/jobs/34/relaunch/"},"summary_fields":{"inventory":{"id":1,"name":"Demo Inventory","description":"","has_active_failures":true,"total_hosts":1,"hosts_with_active_failures":1,"total_groups":0,"groups_with_active_failures":0,"has_inventory_sources":false,"total_inventory_sources":0,"inventory_sources_with_failures":0,"organization_id":1,"kind":""},"project":{"id":7,"name":"Cox-Phase3","description":"","status":"successful","scm_type":"git"},"job_template":{"id":8,"name":"Port Flap","description":""},"unified_job_template":{"id":8,"name":"Port Flap","description":"","unified_job_type":"job"},"created_by":{"id":1,"username":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":""},"modified_by":{"id":1,"username":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":""},"user_capabilities":{"delete":true,"start":true},"labels":{"count":0,"results":[]},"extra_credentials":[],"credentials":[]},"created":"2019-05-14T09:43:16.115516Z","modified":"2019-05-14T09:43:16.177517Z","name":"Port Flap","description":"","job_type":"run","inventory":1,"project":7,"playbook":"main.yml","forks":0,"limit":"","verbosity":1,"extra_vars":"{}","job_tags":"","force_handlers":false,"skip_tags":"","start_at_task":"","timeout":0,"use_fact_cache":false,"unified_job_template":8,"launch_type":"manual","status":"pending","failed":false,"started":null,"finished":null,"elapsed":0.0,"job_args":"","job_cwd":"","job_env":{},"job_explanation":"","execution_node":"","controller_node":"","result_traceback":"","event_processing_finished":false,"job_template":8,"passwords_needed_to_start":[],"ask_diff_mode_on_launch":false,"ask_variables_on_launch":false,"ask_limit_on_launch":false,"ask_tags_on_launch":false,"ask_skip_tags_on_launch":false,"ask_job_type_on_launch":false,"ask_verbosity_on_launch":false,"ask_inventory_on_launch":false,"ask_credential_on_launch":false,"allow_simultaneous":false,"artifacts":{},"scm_revision":"","instance_group":null,"diff_mode":false,"job_slice_number":0,"job_slice_count":1,"credential":null,"vault_credential":null}
```

Comment: You failed to specify your Tower version, but [3.0 has made `extra_vars` more strict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#ug-jobtemplates-extravars); are those conditions applicable to you (3.0, enabled survey, and/or ask on launch = true)?

Comment: Separately, while you didn't ask this, your life will be considerably better if you use the distinction between single and double quotes in shell, as your `curl` command would be less verbose with `-d '{"extra_vars": {"vendor":"juniper"}}'`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Thanks for the comment. To be honest I am using Ansible AWX not the tower and I am running on the latest version possible. Regarding single and double quotes this was my third attempt to call the API. I was using different formats before that.

Comment: Well, Tower is just AWX-for-money, so if you're on the latest AWX then you are on 4, which likely is affected by that change. You skipped over the other two parts: do you have an enabled survey for that template, and/or do you have `ask_variables_on_launch=True` like the docs say?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel -  After turning on the `ask_variables_on_launch=True` it worked. Please submit the answer and I will mark it as the correct. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're very kind, and I'm glad it was something simple :-)

Comment: *Trying to lunch* been there, done that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the fine manual, AWX (and thus Tower) version 3.0 and greater has made `extra_vars` more strict: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#ug-jobtemplates-extravars

If you are running a version greater than 3.0, you will need to either turn on playbook survey or set `ask_variables_on_launch=True` for that template

Answer (score 1):

Tangentially related to the API when utilizing the AWX and Tower CLI I ran into a similar issue of variables not being taken when launching jobs.  The solution was that on the Job Template in Tower the "Prompt on Launch" setting needed to checked for the variable to pass through. So much time wasted on such a simple miss.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using `curl -L ...` and the payload got lost after the redirect. Be sure to double check that if you find the `extra_vars` still gets ignored after ensuring `ask_variables_on_launch=True`.

Comment: I was getting a redirect because the url did not have a trailing /.  (should be `TEMPLATE/launch/`  not `TEMPLATE/launch`). Once I added the trailing slash, the redirect went away.

Comment: @LincolnD Damned if that wasn't my problem.  Thanks.